# CronTab files dump on home directory on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-14.04, cron-task

I have configured a custom script to the crontabs on my Ubuntu 14.04 server as below and cron jobs are working fine.

```
* * * * * wget https://mywebsite.com/cronscript.php
```

However, I have noticed that there are so many files autocreated on home directory(/home/ubuntu) in the name of the cronjob script like below,

```
cronscript.php
cronscript.php.1
cronscript.php.10
cronscript.php.100
.............
.............
.............
cronscript.php.9998
cronscript.php.9999
```

I am not sure why it is creating automatically and also not sure will it impact anything on the server performance since filezilla connection to the home directory took long time may be due to these many files. Also all these files don't have any content and all are 0B size files.

Any suggestions to prevent this happening or auto removing these files will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to download latest file (and overwrite old copy) is to set explicitly the output name and overwrite old file:

```
* * * * * wget -O cronscript.php -c https://mywebsite.com/cronscript.php
```

Setting this to run every minute may load your machine.